# How to save selected Item on a cascading combo box instead of the value to the database in jsp

Tags: java, html, jsp

I am trying to save selected items on three cascading dropdown list which is loaded from the database using jsp. But when I save it, the values will be saved to the database instead of the selected items. I have tried all I could including searching the web but haven't found solution to the problem.

I created an index.jsp page that will load three dropdown box (country, city and state). When the program runs, the index will load the countries in the first dropdown from a database. The selection of a country will determine the which state to load. The selection of a state will determine which city to load also.

Now when I save the selection to the database, the values will be saved to the database instead of the selected items.

This is the index.jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Save To Database</title>


    <script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
        var xmlHttp
        var xmlHttp
        function showState(str) {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp == null) {
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                return;
            }
            var url = "state.jsp";
            url += "?count=" + str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange;
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }

        function stateChange() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
                document.getElementById("state").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
            }
        }

        function showCity(str) {
            if (typeof XMLHttpRequest != "undefined") {
                xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
            }
            else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
                xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            }
            if (xmlHttp == null) {
                alert("Browser does not support XMLHTTP Request")
                return;
            }
            var url = "city.jsp";
            url += "?count=" + str;
            xmlHttp.onreadystatechange = stateChange1;
            xmlHttp.open("GET", url, true);
            xmlHttp.send(null);
        }
        function stateChange1() {
            if (xmlHttp.readyState == 4 || xmlHttp.readyState == "complete") {
                document.getElementById("city").innerHTML = xmlHttp.responseText
            }
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Testing Save to DB Using Dynamic Combo Box!</h1>



    <form method="post" action="SaveToDB.jsp">

        <select name='country' onchange="showState(this.value)">  
            <option value="none">Select</option>  
            <%
                Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();
                Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test", "root", "");
                Statement stmt = con.createStatement();
                ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from country");
                while (rs.next()) {
            %>
            <option value="<%=rs.getString(1)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%>   </option>  
            <%
                }
            %>
        </select>  
        <br>  
        <div id='state'>  
            <select name='state' >  
                <option value='-1'></option>  
            </select>  
        </div>  

        <div id='city'>  
            <select name='city' >  
                <option value='-1'></option>  
            </select>  
        </div>        


        <input name="SavtToDB" type="Submit" value="Save to DB">                 
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

This is the state.jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String country=request.getParameter("count");  
String buffer="<select name='state' onchange='showCity(this.value);'><option value='-1'>Select</option>";  
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");  
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from state where countryid='"+country+"' ");  
while(rs.next()){
buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(1)+"'>"+rs.getString(3)+"</option>";
}
buffer = buffer+"</select>";
response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
}
catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

This is the city.jsp code:

```
<%@page import="java.sql.*"%>
<%
String state=request.getParameter("count");  
String buffer="<select name='city'><option value='-1'>Select</option>";  
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver").newInstance();  
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root","");  
Statement stmt = con.createStatement();  
ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery("Select * from city where stateid='"+state+"' ");  
while(rs.next()){
buffer=buffer+"<option value='"+rs.getString(2)+"'>"+rs.getString(3)+"</option>";  
}  
buffer=buffer+"</select>";  
response.getWriter().println(buffer); 
}
catch(Exception e){
 System.out.println(e);
}
%>
```

This is the SaveToDB.jsp code:

```
<%@ page import ="java.sql.*" %>
<%

String getCountry = request.getParameter("country");
String getState = request.getParameter("state");
String getCity = request.getParameter("city");

Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test","root", "");
Statement st = con.createStatement();
int
i = st.executeUpdate("insert into savetodb(SelectedCountry, SelectedState, SelectedCity) values ('" + getCountry + "','" + getState + "','" + getCity + "')");
if (i > 0) {

   %>

<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Saved Successfully!! \n Login to access your Dashboard!');
    window.location='index.jsp';
</script>
<%     

} else {
%>

<script language='javascript'>
    window.alert('Not Saved Try again!');
    window.location='index.jsp';
</script>
 <%     
}
%>
```

This are the databases creation:

for country:

```
CREATE TABLE country (countryid BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, countryname VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (countryid));
```

for state:

```
CREATE TABLE `state` (stateid BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, countryid INT, `state` VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (stateid));
```

for city:

```
CREATE TABLE city (cityid BIGINT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, stateid INT, city VARCHAR(255), PRIMARY KEY (cityid));
```

for saveToDB:

```
CREATE TABLE savetodb (`SelectedCountry` VARCHAR(50), `SelectedState` VARCHAR(50), `SelectedCity` VARCHAR(50));
```

I expect that when I have selected the country, state and city on the combo box (which successfully loads to the combo box from county.db) and save the selection to saveToDB, it should save what is selected. But the values (1,2 or 3) is saved. Thank you for your assistance in anticipation folks.

Comment: That's a lot of code to read. Is this truly the simplest example of the problem you are facing?

Comment: In select drop down whatever you will pass in option value that will save in database.  make it  same option value and name in drop down and check: <option value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%>   </option>

Comment: @Stewart, I didn't know how to explain the problem than to be detailed because I am using it for a project work. But I think so far, the title captures the whole problem I am trying to solve. You could assist me by please going through the code or you could refer me to a site that will be of help because I have tried all I could.
I might be missing something out. Thank you.

Comment: I have tried `<option value="<%=rs.getString(2)%>"><%=rs.getString(2)%> </option>` but the problem I have with that is: loading the first combo box from the database will be successful but subsequent combo boxes will not load because of the concatenation. Could you help me check and suggest possibly easier way to go about the problem? Thank you @ShivendraSingh